# What is a reference oscillator which is used in Costas receiver?

Tags: signal-processing, demodulation

A Costas receiver has a voltage-controlled oscillator, which is sometimes referred to as reference oscillator. What is the input and output of this reference oscillator?

[image]

Comment: probably I and Q; wanna provide a block diagram?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13t8BOBcCDL7I5upUDy_o_tOjzemY3md4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In this what is the actual input to the oscillator, whole output signal, it amplitude or the phase, and how is its output affected?

Comment: I've edited in your picture. For future reference, please don't sprinkle in additional information in the comments, nor google drive links. Instead, edit your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The input is a frequency control, a function of the difference between its output and the phase it's tracking. This control comes from another block.

The output is a clock signal, of the correct phase to demodulate the clocked data it's tracking.